# how to create a C++20 module with export header-import which doesn't mess with preprocessor defines of other includes?

Tags: c++, c++20, preprocessor, c++-modules

I'm working with msvc 17.7.0 and am struggling to understand how to create a simple module in the short cut way using header-imports.
What i'm trying is to create a module `TestModule.ixx` like

```
export module TestModule;
export import "TestDefine2.hpp";
```

where `TestDefine2.hpp` is a container for all headers to import

```
#ifndef Included_TestDefine2
#define Included_TestDefine2
#include "TestDefine.hpp"
#endif
```

and `TestDefine.hpp` would contain all headers:

(I'm trying to create a module for the [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library and [not for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170) the [std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library) but for simplicity i'm only adding on of the headers which is transitively included and allows to show the problem)

```
#ifndef Included_TestDefine
#define Included_TestDefine
#include <cerrno>
#endif
```

The module is then used like this (f.e. in `main.cpp`)

```
//#include <cerrno> // errno is defined when including cerrno before the import
import TestModule;
#include <cerrno> // errno is not defined when including cerrno after the import

auto asdfasdf = errno;
```

When `cerrno` is included after the import msvc complains about a

```
error C2065: 'errno': undeclared identifier
```

and it doesn't when it's included before the import (the behavior is the same for `/std:c++20` and `/std:c++latest`).

While this can be fixed easily in this small example i'm imagining refactoring parts of a big codebase to use eigen as a module and it seems almost unavoidable to have arbitrary include orders without having to include everything which can have these problems before any import.

Is there anything which can be done about that?

Am i using modules wrong?

Would i have to completely patch/rewrite eigen in order to work around this?

Or is including all "problematic" headers before any import the only option?

Comment: `#pragma once` is something I would not mix with modules. It's an old pre-module hack for MSVC.

Comment: @MSalters oh, wasn't aware of that. Changed it to include guards but the behavior stays the same.

Comment: Have you seen this? [Standard library named module considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170#standard-library-named-module-considerations) I am not sure it applies to you, but it does mention a distinction between `<cerrno>` and `errno.h`. Ditto re. other C-specific headers.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I'm aware of it but just tried and it doesn't seem to make a difference, whether i include `errno.h` only in the consumer (instead of `cerrno`) or only in the import header (instead of `cerrno`) or in both (instead of `cerrno`). So far, only moving the `include` in the consumer before or after the `import` makes a difference.

Comment: @ridilculous Yeah, this is a toughie. I doubt the `eigen` library plays nice with modules at all! When you put an include above the `export module` declaration, are you also putting it _after_ a `module;` statement? In other words, are you correctly implementing the _global module fragment_? Unfortunately, names appearing in the global module fragment will not be automatically exported. You can however, manually export them in the module purvue (after `export module`).

Comment: @tbxfreeware i only have two lines in the whole `ixx` module file - `export module TestModule;`and `export import "TestDefine2.hpp";`. The `#include <cerrno>` which makes the difference is in the consumer where i import the resulting module. But i also tested to additionally put `#include <cerrno>` in the global module fragment, between `module;` and `export module TestModule;` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Is manually exporting what vector<bool> describes as [discarded declarations](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/10/07/modules-3.html#discarded-declarations)? i tried that too but it didn't work for `errno` and it would be a lil awful :)

Comment: "Manually exporting" is my phrase. What I mean, is simply redeclaring (but not redefining) the names from a header file that you need to export, and preceding each declaration with the word `export`. If, for instance, the include file in the _global module fragment_ declared `int f();`, you could redeclare it as `export int f();` in the module purview section of the file. As for `errno`, because it is a macro, I think your best bet is to include `errno.h` in the _global module fragment_ of any module that needs it.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I tried the global module fragment and for the macros it works within the module files but it doesn't solve the consumer side in any cpp file where it makes a difference whether the `include` with the macro stays before or after the `import`.

Comment: Sadly, there may be no solution for what you need. I recently switched to `import std` in the programs where I am experimenting with modules. So far, it works great. I have been able to eliminate the global module fragment completely. From top to bottom, I'm only using modules. Microsoft, however, stresses that the feature is still experimental. Integrating with third-party `cpp` libraries is likely to be difficult, and may be impossible.